# Apache error 500 internal error , but reload, it work

Tags: apache, internal

I have a website forurl.co
It is shortener, the homepage is working well,but the internal link, eg

```
http://forurl.co/queratocone_392849
```

First access, it is showing blank page and error log:

> 162.244.10.213 - - [27/Apr/2014:16:33:47 +0000] "GET /queratocone_392849 HTTP/1.1" 500 26 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"

It is weird !!!!
But, if i reload the page again, it works !!!!
It is happening on thousand links on my website !
Could you guys pls give me hand!

Comment: That looks more like access log than error log.

Comment: Got very similar scenario, 500 errors come out when there are more than 20 users and what helps is to restart apache. Still don't have solution...